# Using GCC/Sublime to compile SDL programs on Linux

Tags: c++, c, gcc, sublimetext2, sdl

How can I use either GCC or the Sublime IDE to compile my SDL based project on Linux?

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -lSDL2
```

I have tried this and I just get errors that seem to be pointing to the idea that either the program isn't pointing at the library the right way or the compiler isn't recognizing the library. On Sublime I have essentially done the same thing by creating my own build system for SDL, but it doesn't really seem to do anything at all. What might I be doing wrong?

```
{
     "cmd" : [ "gcc", "$file", "-o", "-lSDL2" ] 
{
```

I hope this question is appropriate on this stack, it can be considered Linux tooling but the Linux and Unix stack doesn't suggest programming questions unless they consist of shell scripting.

Here is just the basic Hello World that I am testing (Obviously not quite formatted correctly, but you get the idea.) :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int win = 1;
SDL_Event event;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_WM_SetCaption("Window", NULL);
SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
while (win) {
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        win = 0;
}
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

When the program is compiled I use the GCC command posted at the top and get these errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:19:37: error: ‘SDL_WM_SetCaption’ was not declared in this scope
 SDL_WM_SetCaption("Window", NULL);
                                 ^
main.cpp:20:36: error: ‘SDL_HWSURFACE’ was not declared in this scope
 SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
                                ^
main.cpp:20:49: error: ‘SDL_SetVideoMode’ was not declared in this scope
 SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
                                             ^
```

I have also tried pointing directly to header files in GCC with:

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -l/usr/include/SDL2
```

I did check to make sure that the header files were in usr/include/SDL2, maybe the actual library isn't installed in the right place for development?

Comment: Could you show us the actual errors you're getting?

Comment: Some like this:    main.c:20:36: error: ‘SDL_HWSURFACE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);

Comment: and others like this @Ixrec main.cpp:20:49: error: ‘SDL_SetVideoMode’ was not declared in this scope
     SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);

Comment: I've never used SDL, but getting "not declared" on a library symbol usually means you forgot to include that library's header files (which I believe is done with the -i option for commandline gcc).

Comment: It was declared through gcc when it was compiled, I looked through the gcc documentation and it seems as though it was declared in the right place. I also tried -lSDL and -lSDL2 @Ixrec

Comment: What does "delcared through gcc" mean? The few times I've used gcc from the command line, using -i and/or -I on the command line was the only way to include library headers.

Comment: Just another way of saying that it was included. Not necessary a programming term but just me saying that I included it that way. @Ixrec But I am pretty sure that is the only way

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your entire code (if it is short) or create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us exactly what you're doing. Include the exact build command you're running on the command line, and the **full output** of that command. We can't help you unless we know what you're doing. It sounds like you haven't included all of the correct header files in your program, and/or there is some other programming error.

Comment: All code and errors have been added to the main question. @MattDMo

Comment: Why you're using SDL 1? I suggest you to switch to SDL 2, it's newer and better.

Comment: I am using SDL 2, I just changed that in the source @HolyBlackCat

Comment: There is no such directory as `/user/include/SDL2`, the first directory should be `/usr`.

Comment: I did realize that and have updated the gcc command to `gcc main.cpp -o main -l/usr/include/SDL2` I am however still getting the same errors @MattDMo

Comment: `>> I am using SDL 2, I just changed that in the source` In SDL 2 there is no such functions as `SDL_WM_SetCaption` and `SDL_SetVideoMode`. You must use `SDL_CreateWindow` instead. See this: http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAPI

Comment: Ahh, the code was the problem. Great. Thank you @HolyBlackCat

Answer (score 1):

The errors from GCC were cause by calling functions in SDL2 that didn't exist. Changing the previous SDL Video calls to:

```
SDL_CreateWindow(
"Window",
SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
640,
480,
SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
);
```

was the right way to create a window in SDL 2;

Following with the GCC commands:

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -lSDL2
```

Compiled the code correctly and thus made it executable. Thank you for pointing that out @HolyBlackCat